# Disable Column Sorting Or Add Row Numbers Inside Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Here the problem

I have a piece of data in the database. The data consists of several columns as below

```
row_num   name       age
1         John       21
2         Michelle   20
3         Robert     22
```

Then I display the data using the datatable. I disable sorting for the row_num column by using orderable = false.

Here the code of datatable i used

```
$('#data').DataTable({
  serverside: true,
  ajax: 'data.php',
  columns: [
    { data: 'row_num', orderable: false},
    { data: 'name' },
    { data: 'age' }
)}
```

The column row_num is cannot be sorted, and it does. But when I sort the name column or age column, the row_num column is also sorted. I don't want that.

Example when sorting the age column

```
row_num    name      age
2          Michelle  20
1          John      21
3          Robert    22
```

What I want

```
row_num    name      age
1          Michelle  20
2          John      21
3          Robert    22
```

This also has an effect when performing data searches, for example searching for Robert's data

```
row_num    name      age
3          Robert    22
```

Though it should be

```
row_num    name      age
1          Robert    22
```

I know it happens because the data from row_num is fetched from the database.I just want to label the row numbers inside the datatable.

Is there a solution so that the row_num column is not sorted, or is there a solution to provide numbers per row in the datatable?

Answer (score 0):

closed.
Just add this line

```
 detail_table.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
   detail_table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
       cell.innerHTML = i+1;
   } );
 } ).draw();
```